# ping script with a ms threshold, which then saves to a file AND send a email

Tags: bash, awk, ping

I have written a script in bash(my first one) with help through google and stackexchange.
What the script does is that is takes a threshold value and compares it to the ms time result from the ping. If the ms time value is higher then the threshold value, it echos out the ping result into a .log file(pingscript.log)

What I also want the script to do is to send out a mail when the ping ms time is above the threshold value.

I have tried to pipe it to a mail command, but without any luck. =(

Anyone else know how to solve it?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
echo "You must enter 1 command line arguments - The address which you want to ping against"
exit
fi

while true; do
ping -c 1 $1 | awk -v time="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" -Ftime= 'NF>1{if ($2+0 > 5) print $1 $2 $4 $3 $5 " "time >> "pingscript.log" }'
sleep 2
done
```

Comment: start by googling examples of usage of mailx (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailx) and mutt (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutt_%28email_client%29). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

This is what I finally ended up with.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "You must enter 1 command line arguments - The address which you want to ping against"
exit
fi

hostname=$(hostname)

while true; do

RESULT=$(ping -c 1 $1 | awk -v time="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" -Ftime= 'NF>1{if ($2+0 > 1) print $1 $2 $4 $3 $5 " "time }')

if [ "$RESULT" != "" ]; then
echo $RESULT >> pingscript.log
echo $RESULT | mail -s "pingAlert between $hostname -  $1" foo@bar.com
fi

sleep 2
done
```

This will give foo@bar.com an email with the ping result if the ms time result is higher then the threshold value in the script.